# jclouds ScriptBuilder not sending the statement correctly to execute

Tags: java, bash, centos6, rackspace, jclouds

I am trying to build a bash script dynamically and created the file on rackspace centos instance and one of the following behave differently not sure what i am missing here.

```
String script = new ScriptBuilder()
.addStatement(exec("echo ' expect \"Enter Password :\"'  >> config.sh "))    
.addStatement(exec("echo ' send -- \"123\"'  >> config.sh "))               
.addStatement(exec("echo ' send -- \"\\r\"'  >> config.sh "))   
                .render(OsFamily.UNIX);
```

When I loggin to the box and view config.sh .

```
expect "Enter Password:"
send -- "123"
"send --"
```

But I want to see

```
expect "Enter Password:"
send -- "123"
send -- "\r"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly using the `ScriptBuilder` class, it is a better idea to use the `Statements` helper class. It has a couple methods that might help you:

- [Statements.createOrOverwriteFile](http://jclouds.apache.org/reference/javadoc/1.7.x/org/jclouds/scriptbuilder/domain/Statements.html#createOrOverwriteFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Iterable)): I'd use this. You could have the script pre-created in a file in the class path, and just read the contents of the file to create the equivalent one in the server.
- [Statements.appendFile](http://jclouds.apache.org/reference/javadoc/1.7.x/org/jclouds/scriptbuilder/domain/Statements.html#appendFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Iterable)): You can use this statement to append a set of lines to a file.

Both scripts are a better option that directly using the `ScriptBuilder`. If you end up with more than one statement, you can add them to a `StatementList` (which is also a Statement).

Answer (score 0):

This is just bash escaping issue that you have run into here with Java. Have you tried something like:

```
String script = new ScriptBuilder()
   .addStatement(exec("echo ' expect \"Enter Password :\"'  >> config.sh "))    
   .addStatement(exec("echo ' send -- \"123\"'  >> config.sh "))               
   .addStatement(exec("( echo ' send -- '; echo '\r' )  >> config.sh ") 
   .render(OsFamily.UNIX);
```